# pass parameter to selector pointed function

Tags: ios, swift2

I am programming with Swift 2.1.

I have a function in class:

```
private func doTask(button: UIButton) {...}
```

I want to call this function after 2 seconds, I know I could use :

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: "doTask", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

But, in the `selector` part, how can I pass the parameter `button: UIButton` to `doTask`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timers can only call methods that take a timer as their parameter. Selectors are just names of methods; they can't carry data. You have to make a new method that takes a timer and calls `doTask`. You can pass data in the `userInfo` parameter if you want to configure things, but you still need an extra method.

This kind of timer probably isn't what you want anyway. Just use `dispatch_after`.

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    doTask(button)
}
```

You can see [Matt's implementation of `delay()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/97337) that makes this a little easier to use.